# A metric for which set of rational numbers complete

Tags: metric-spaces

Does there exist a metric  on $\mathbb{Q}$ which is equivalent

to the standard metric but $(\mathbb{Q}, d)$ is complete.??

My attempt :

We know that with respect to standard metric, each singleton is closed subsets.

Since we know that a countable union of nowhere dense sets in a metric space need not be nowhere dense.

As for example, consider the set of rational numbers as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$,  we can write  $\mathbb{Q}$  as the union of singleton set, which of course nowhere dense sets in $\mathbb{R}$.

But,  of  closure ($\mathbb{Q}$)  is $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ is everywhere dense in $\mathbb{R}$ and  hence, $\mathbb{Q}$ is not nowhere dense set in $\mathbb{R}$. 
Therefore,  there exist a metric  s. t  $(\mathbb{Q}, d)$ is complete.

Is my arguments true.??

Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [BCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem), a countable complete metric space is not a union of nowhere dense sets; every singleton is nowhere dense; $\Bbb Q$ is countable.

---

Also your argument does not actually establish a metric on $\Bbb Q$ that makes $\Bbb Q$ complete. You talked about nowhere dense sets and I don't know what you want.

Comment: Then what can you say about your explanation?

Comment: No. Finite union of nowhere dense set is  nowhere dense but not countable number.

Comment: That still has nothing to do with a metric on $\Bbb Q$ making it complete.

Comment: # Kenny, I know that  Q  has been expressed as a countable union of singleton sets.

Comment: You can check your result.

Comment: You still haven't addressed the question, i.e. to show that there is a metric on Q that makes it complete.

Comment: Actually my question is:  does there exist a metric d on Q which is equivalent to the standard metric but (Q, d) is complete.??

Comment: Your argument still doesn't address that.

Comment: Can you help to give answer of this question? Is this result false or true?

Comment: Okk thanks. I got answer from your help.

Comment: A countable complete metric space has an isolated points. But Q has no isolated points although Q is countable. Hence (Q, d) is not complete.